# Spring 4 Jpa caching query, cant get recently updated value

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring application configured with a class for database management like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/${app.execution.environment}/application.properties" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example", entityManagerFactoryRef = "mysqlEntityManager", transactionManagerRef = "mysqlTransactionManager")
public class MysqlHibernateConfig {
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@Primary
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mysqlEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(mysqlDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.example" });

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    em.setJpaPropertyMap(hibernateProperties());
    return em;
}

@Primary
@Bean
public DataSource mysqlDataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("mysql.jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("mysql.jdbc.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("mysql.jdbc.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("mysql.jdbc.password"));
    return dataSource;
}

@Primary
@Bean
@Autowired
public JpaTransactionManager mysqlTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(mysqlEntityManager().getObject());
    return txManager;
}

private HashMap<String, Object> hibernateProperties() {
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("mysql.hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
    return properties;
}
}
```

I then have a Jpa class like this:

```
public interface JpaClass extends JpaRepository<EntityObject, Long> {
      EntityObject findById(String entityId);
}
```

I call have a process that updates the value which is returned in the EntityObject above.  I then need to get the updated value from the database, but when i query it again in a period shorter than 3 minutes or so (not sure of the exact time) I get back the exact same value.  If I dont let the process run for a period of time, I can get my updated value, but i need to be able to get it immediately.  How can this be accomplished?

Comment: do a flush (word count)

Comment: on whatever you are updating in your daos / query. flush will update the changes  but doesnt commit. for example you are using presistance manager than you should able to call flush. if you are using session you call the session.flush()

Comment: ok i understand, I have been trying to figure out how to do that with my specific example, I will have to do some more research, but if you happen to know how i would with this example, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You might want to look into the hibernate property `hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion`.

Comment: @gonzo tried adding this properties.put("hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion",
                true); in the hibernateProperties() method, but it did not solve my problem, thanks for the suggestion though.